# How to control phone while inside VR device without an action button

Tags: technology, phone, hardware

I bought a VR device that can hold your phone to give a VR experience, however I only discovered after I got home that I have no way of controlling anything while my phone is inside the VR device.

I downloaded the google cardboard app thinking it might hold a solution but I can't even make a menu selection without opening the device and tapping on my phone.

I was thinking of possibly using earphones you get with the phone as it normally has a answer button which could act as an action button, but I no longer have mine.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I did not buy it here, but here is a link to the product I own: http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/VR-Arruda-Small-Wasp-3D-Magic-Mirror-Headset-Virtual-Reality-VR-BOX-ARRUDA-Google-Cardboard-3D/139373_32597475952.html

Comment: ... can you press the buttons with your nose?

Comment: Haha good idea but no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the apps have a gaze setting. So instead of pressing a button you can simply stare at the button you want to "click" and after a while it will select it if you stare at it long enough.

That is the closest you will get to control on a buttonless VR device.

Answer (score 2):

There are some tricks online of using copper tape or aluminum foil to "extend" the capacity touch to outside the VR case.
Examples:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Na7HsX_N-o

http://www.instructables.com/id/Copper-tape-touch-extension-for-Cardboard-VR-kits/

Comment: Wow that is amazing. I never knew foil would do that. It is very DIY though and seems like it only works about 80% of the time. Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

My dad bought VR glasses which had the same problem. He said that Google cardboard has a magnet control. So we tested by swiping a magnet on the outside of the glass and we found the working spot. Stare at an option and just swipe the magnet on the spot.

Answer (score 0):

Without an integrated controller, your best bet is an external one, such as a bluetooth controller. These are readily available online for relatively cheap: For [example](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Virtoba-Control-Bluetooth-Controller-Serviceable/dp/B01CRXJBCU).

I know that the Samsung VR headset comes with an integrated controller that allows you to swipe by the side of the device to control, but as you don't have one of those, it isn't as relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Fulldive VR app, it's available for iOS and Android

With it you can browse photos, videos, also there is a browser for internet, so you can browse internet in your VR glasses.

I had an idea to use AirDroid through the Fulldive's browser, so you can control your phone, write SMS from inside VR glasses but I didn't try.